# Grabbing first names and storing in a list within a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I need to extract the first names of bob and alice from the dictionary and store it in list7. I have tried slicing and get error that my value exceeds range and have currently tried this code and receive an error as well.

```
directory = [{'firstName':"bob",'department':"Accounting",'salary':50000{'firstName':"alice",'department':"Marketing",'salary':100000}]

list7[]

#My Code
list7 = [ sub['firstName'] for sub in directory ]
```

Comment: You're missing a `}, ` after `50000` in your `dict` definition. Also `list7[]` would raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works:

```py
directory = [
    {"firstName": "bob", "department": "Accounting", "salary": 50000},
    {"firstName": "alice", "department": "Marketing", "salary": 100000},
]

list7 = [sub["firstName"] for sub in directory]
print(list7)
# ['bob', 'alice']
```